# How does one extend radial basis function (RBF) networks formally from regularization but with vector valued outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, regularization, radial-basis

I was reading the [following paper on hyper & radial basis function (HBFs & RBFs) networks](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1140.pdf) and also [this one](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1167.pdf) that kind of summarizes the first one and was trying to understand how to extend their results to **vector values outputs**.

In the paper they mainly discuss all the result for real value outputs but I can't seem to find where they discuss the results for multi-valued outputs. On page 29 they seem to imply they did talk about this but its unclear. In particular they say:

> we have so far considered GRBFs as a technique to solve the problem of approximating real values functions $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$, ...

however, as far as I can tell they only explain and give the equations for the case $f:R^n \rightarrow R$. I was wondering if people understood how to extend HBFs networks to multiple outputs.

In particular this is more or less what I conjecture the optimization problem is and its solution (but wasn't sure if I could derive it).

So we would consider the variational optimization problem (similar to the one on the paper):

$$ H[f] = \sum^N_{i=1} \frac{1}{2} \| y_i - f(x_i) \|^2 + \lambda \| Pf \|^2$$

where $f(x_i), y_i \in R^m$.

And I would hope the solution would look something like this:

$$ y_i = [..., y_{i,j} ,...] = [..., f(x_i)_j , ...] = [..., \sum^K_{k=1} c_{k,j} G(\| x_i - t_k \|^2),...]$$

where $K$ is the number of adjustable centers (and hence number of hidden units), $c_{a,j}$ are the weights from hidden unit a to output unit $j$. In fact I hope this can be expressed in the following network:

[image]

Furthermore, on top of that, I think the gradient descent equations have to be re-derived.

Comment: Why would you do it for all coordinates simultaneously? For $f:R^n \to R^m$, take $f = (f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m)$ and optimize for each $f_j$ separately.

Comment: @sandris What do you mean by "Why would you do it for all coordinates simultaneously?"? Do you mean why I would minimize the error of the vectors? Or why would I choose operator P that correlates the coordinates?

Comment: Ah, okay, so P correlates the coordinates, makes sense then.

Comment: @sandris I think it might dependent on the specific differential operator P that is chosen. However, since it has an adjoint, it should be linear I believe..